# Flowing user credentials from Dynamics CRM to Web API

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to flow the user credentials from a CRM plug-in to a web API hosted in Azure?

I'm working on a project where a Dynamics CRM plug-in will make a call to a custom ASP.Net Core 2.0 Web API hosted in the same Azure tenant.

I have no Dynamics CRM experience; we have a team member who has done a lot of CRM integration, but he's always used a service account to connect to the other application.
I'm trying to avoid that.

Ideally, this web API would perform some work using the credentials of the CRM user, since the user's credentials will be valid in both CRM and the web API.

I would really like to have the user's credentials (such as email) come from a trusted authority and not just passed by the caller.  I already have code that pulls the user's email (for example) from the user's Claims (from another part of the project).

In my perfect scenario, the plug-in code would pass the user's OpenID Connect to the web API; but I've found nothing that indicates that CRM supports OpenID Connect.
I have seen articles that talk about calling CRM from an external application using Oauth, but nothing that shows CRM calling a service with any kind of token-based authentication.

A fallback would be to use an OAuth bearer token, and have the plug-in pass the user's information to the web API.

Does anyone have any information on how to flow the CRM user's credentials to a web API call, or acquiring a bearer token to pass to a web API?

Thanks

Comment: [This repository](https://github.com/jlattimer/CrmWebApiCSharp) may contain a useful example similar to your scenario.

Comment: Thanks - this appears to be getting an OAUTH2 bearer token from Azure using a client ID and secret, not getting a token using the current user's credentials.  This is pretty much what I had to end up doing.